# Google Analytics tracking some pageviews as just a forward slash

Tags: url, analytics

Really strange. One of my posts is being tracked half the time in Google Analytics as its correct permalink, while the other half of the pageviews are coming from a single forward slash that is attributed with the same Page Title.

Example:

```
Title of Page: Official iPhone Unlock
Correct URL of page: /official-iphone-unlock
Two URL's being tracked with that page title:/official-iphone-unlock/
```

So, needless to say, this is throwing off my numbers as I'm getting pageviews for this page under both URLs, and really hard to figure out what the issue is. I'm using ECWID shopping cart, and I'm suspicious that it's their way of tracking things, but I can't prove it. But the issue started around the time I enabled their tracking code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried segmenting the traffic for these pages by browser?

First find the page:
  Behavior > Site Content > All Pages (then search for your pages)

...then cross-drill by browser segment:
  Secondary Dimension > Visitors > Browsers

One possibility that comes to mind is that some browsers may auto-append a slash to the end of URLs without a file extension, while others may not. For example, Chrome forwards a /foo URL to /foo/ for me. It may only be specific versions of a browser that exhibits this behavior -- like IE9 for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the filter to remove the trailing slashes - check this `https://www.petramanos.com/ecommerce-google-analytics/remove-slashes-end-urls-google-analytics`